# how to insert based on the inserting date

Tags: sql-server

I have a table tbl1(account, last_contact_date, insert_date). I defined the primary key is account and last_contact_date. For example

```
account    last_contact_date    insert_date
0001       09/01/2012           10/01/2012
0001       09/02/2012           10/02/2012
```

Now I have a new record, which is from another temporary table #tmp(account, last_contact_date). Based on the last_contact_date or insert_date, I will insert it conditionally:
(1) if the inserting date is the same day, I will update the account with the max last_contact_date;

```
(0001, 09/01/2012, 10/02/2012) --no
(0001, 09/02/2012, 10/02/2012) --no
(0001, 09/03/2012, 10/02/2012) --update
```

(2) if the inserting date is the day before, do nothing (I know this would never happen)

```
(0001, 09/01/2012, 10/01/2012) --no
(0001, 09/02/2012, 10/01/2012) --no
(0001, 09/03/2012, 10/01/2012) --no
```

(3) if the inserting date is the next day or later, I will insert a new record with the max last_contact_date.

```
(0001, 09/01/2012, 10/03/2012) --no
(0001, 09/02/2012, 10/03/2012) --no
(0001, 09/03/2012, 10/03/2012) --insert
```

Can anybody help me how to write this query? I am really run out of idea.

Update: I end up writing above logic using cursor. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use procedures to do this?

Comment: In what context are you performing the insert?  A trigger?  stored procedure?

Comment: Before, next day, later, etc... based on which day? Today? last_contact_date?

Comment: This is part of a stored procedure.

Comment: And the new record is from a temporary table, not parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need an IF to handle this case, like this (assuming you have the current account and insert_date in variables:

```
-- First try to update
UPDATE tbl1 SET <whatever you need to update>
WHERE account = @account AND insert_date = @insert_date
    AND last_contact_date = 
        (SELECT MAX(last_contact_date) FROM tbl1
         WHERE account = @account AND insert_date = @insert_date)

-- Update failed because no matching record was found?
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT <new record>
END
```

If several processes/threads do this concurrently, you may get primary key violations because neither one finds a record and then both try to insert. You would need to put this code into a SERIALIZABLE Transaction to prevent this or use some other logical locking mechanism.

Comment: You could also look into using the MERGE command to put it in one statement.

Comment: the new record is from another temp table.

Comment: @diana: My thoughts exactly! However, MERGE is available only starting from SQL Server 2008 (and the OP hasn't specified which version they are using).

Comment: *assuming* that deletions don't occur, if you reverse the order of the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` (and have the `INSERT` include a `NOT EXISTS`) you should avoid the violation/locking issues you mention in the last paragraph.